# close a WPF Dialog Window when the user clicks outside it

Tags: c#, wpf, click, window, minimize

GoodDay, Here i want to minimize the WPF Window, While user clicking outside of the window.

I can easily minimize the window by this code

```
mywindow.WindowState= WindowState.Minimized;
```

but i want minimize the window at the time of clicking outside of the window.

i searched about that. But i can only got the output of various events like, FocusChanged,MouseMove,MouseDown like that. those are not solve my issue

Comment: What exactly do you mean be outside? A parent window belonging to your application or any other window/the desktop? If it's a parent window you could handle the click and navigate down the visual tree to close the window. Otherwise LostFocus as suggested above seems to be a good option.

Comment: @phatoni thanks for your response Outside means, Any other window or desktop . anywhere it may be. also if there is no window opened, only the application window is currently opened. If we click outside of the wpf window its need to be minimize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `Deactivated`event. Have a look at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.deactivated(v=vs.110).aspx) for further information.

> A window is deactivated (becomes a background window) when:
>
> ```
> A user switches to another window in the current application.
>
> A user switches to the window in another application by using ALT+TAB or by using Task Manager.
>
> A user clicks the taskbar button for a window in another application.
> ```